# MySQL summary status table to store results of operations

Tags: mysql, import, summary

I have a MySQL (5.6) database on my local workstation into which I routinely pull large datasets to perform analysis on. I have a separate SQL script for each dataset that imports the data and reformats it when needed (notably to convert date formats). In addition, I have other scripts that perform detailed analysis on the data.

For quality assurance, I would like to have a table named **ImportLog** that stores a record to capture the result of each import that is run. This table would look like the following:

```
ImportName    DateRun        RowsImported
----------    -------        ------------
ImportASR     2015-08-29     12902
ImportEAD     2015-08-30     18023
ImportHRData  2015-08-30     122376
```

The column definitions for **ImportLog** are as follows:

```
ImportName    // the name of the script that is run
DateRun       // the date that the script is run
RowsImported  // the count of records imported in the run.
```

At the very end of each script would be the code to write one line to this table with the relevant data. For example, let's say that I ran the script named ImportASR on 8/29/2015 and it imported 12,902 records. At the end of the script, I want to append one record to **ImportLog** (like the first record in the table above) using something like this:

```
INSERT INTO ImportLog
    VALUES("ImportASR",$DateRun,$RowCunt);
```

Every time I run one of the import scripts, it would add a row to the **ImportLog** table with the appropriate data.

My question is: How do I populate the $DateRun variable with the current date and the $RowCount variable with the row count of the newly imported ASR dataset? Or am I trying to approach this from the wrong angle?

Comment: Possibly I am misunderstanding your question - in your mysql scripts it should possible to include create table statements. If you want to know the rows affected by the previous operation you can use mysql_affected_rows() (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-function.mysql-affected-rows.html) although there are some provisos to this for some operations.

Comment: Giles, I edited my question in the hope of clarifying what I want to do; did that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing this morning I stumbled upon the answer to my problem; it was amazingly simple, and to my surprise it didn't need the use of any variables. The code to put at the end of each import script is something like:

```
INSERT INTO ImportLog
  "Script: ImportASR",
  SELECT NOW(),
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ASR_Full);
```

The InportLog table is initially defined like so:

```
CREATE TABLE LPIS_SearchMatchLog (
  ImportName VARCHAR(25),
  DateRun DATETIME,
  RowCount INT
);
```

Hope this helps someone else!